# Is it a good practice to create a class between my own scripts and mono behavior?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I have bound the `CombatController` to an object called "godObject". In the `Start()` method, I call `init()` functions on other classes. I did this so I can control the order in which objects are initialized since, for example, the character controller relies on the grid controller being initialized.

Quick diagram:

```
--------------------   calls 
| CombatController | ----------> CameraController.init(); 
--------------------      |
                          | ---> GridController.init();
                          |
                          | ---> CharacterController.init();
```

So, now I have a slight problem. I have multiple properties that I need in every controller. At the moment, I have bound everything to the combat controller itself. That means that, in every controller, I have to get an instance of the CombatController via `GameObject.Find("godObject).GetComponent<CombatController>()`. To be honest, I don't think this is good design.

My idea now was to create a `BaseCombatController` that extends `MonoBehavior`, and then have all other classes like `GridController`, `CharacterController` etc. extend the `BaseCombatController`. It might look like this:

```
public class BaseCombatController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject activePlayer;

    public void setActivePlayer(GameObject player) {
        this.activePlayer = player;
    }

    ... more stuff to come ...
}
```

This way, I could access `activePlayer` everywhere without the need to create a new instance of the `CombatController`. However, I'm not sure if this doesn't have possible side effects.

So, lots of text for a simple question, is that safe to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use inheritance in Unity all the time. The trick, like you have in the question, is to allow your base class to inherit from monobehavior. For Example:

```
public class Base Item : Monobehavior 
{
   public string ItemName;
   public int Price;
   public virtual void PickUp(){//pickup logic}
   //Additional functions. Update etc. Make them virtual.
}
```

This class sets up what an item should do. Then in a derived class you can change and extend this behavior.

```
public class Coin : BaseItem
{
    //properties set in the inspector
    public override void PickUp(){//override pickup logic}
}
```

I have used this design pattern a lot over the past year, and am currently using it in a retail product. I would say go for it! Unity seems to favor components over inheritance, but you could easily use them in conjunction with each other.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, nice to know. Wasn't quite sure if that would result in problems. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The thing to be aware of its to not give your parent class all the MonoBehaviour magic functions unless you *absolutely need them* because of the overhead in how those methods are called. It would be even better to have only a single MonoBehavior, but making that change is hard for some people.

Comment: Agreed. The monobehavior "Magic Functions" make calls to the engine and they have a large amount of overhead. Ideally, you would create a single class to call updates, starts, awakes etc. This however, isn't a design pattern for every developer. [This link can give some more information.](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-callshttps://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see this should be safe. If you look into Unity intern or even Microsoft scripts they all extend/inhert (from) each other.

Another thing you could try would be the use of interfaces, here is the Unity Documentation to them: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/interfaces if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that GameObject.Find is pure code smell.

You can do it via the inheritance tree (as discussed earlier) or even better via interfaces (as mentioned by Assasin Bot), or (I am surprised no one mentioned it earlier) via static fields (aka the Singleton pattern).

One thing to add from experience - having to have Inits() called in a specific order is a yellow flag for your design - I've been there myself and found myself drowned by init order management.

As a general advice: Unity gives you two usefull callbacks - Awake() and Start(). If you find yourself needing Init() you are probably not using those two as they were designed.

All the Awakes() are guaranteed  (for acvie objects) to run before first Start(), so do all the internal object initialisation in Awake(), and binding to external objects on Start(). If you find yourself needing finer control - you should probably simplify the design a bit.

As a rule of thumb: all objects should have their internal state (getcomponents<>, list inits etc) in order by the end of Awake(), but they shold not make any calls depending on other objects being ready before Start(). Splitting it this way usually helps a lot

Comment: My entire program is a yellow flag. I build that thing without any experience in unity (or C# for that matter) and I'm currently in the progress of refactoring the entire thing so I don't hate myself later. I recently found out about `Awake()` which actually simplified everything. But thanks a lot for your input! :)